# In Linux, what does "touch ." (touch dot) do?

Tags: linux, shell, touch

I have searched for a similar question here, but found nothing related.

In Linux, the dot (`.`) refers to the directory itself. The `touch` command creates a file, if it does not exist.

**But what does `touch .` (dot as argument) do?**

I have checked the [GNU touch documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/touch-invocation.html) and the [LINFO information about dot](http://www.linfo.org/dot.html), but found nothing related.

I have tried this command in my Fedora and it seems that nothing is changed.

Comment: atime might have changed

Comment: @神秘德里克, thank. That clears things. Now I see it in ls output. Now I consider voting this question for deletion. But maybe there is another thing apart from that that touch does?

Comment: You can strace it. I believe it doesn't do too much work

Comment: Hm, I did not know about strace tool. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GNU touch documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/touch-invocation.html):

> touch changes the access and/or modification timestamps of the specified files.

So, if the file exists, then `touch` modifies it's timestamps. We can check this:

```
$ stat .
File: '.'
Size: 40              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 11h/17d Inode: 2338759     Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/ chronos)   Gid: ( 1000/ chronos)
Context: u:object_r:tmpfs:s0
Access: 2018-10-29 08:06:16.918056344 +0530
Modify: 2018-10-29 08:06:15.484056316 +0530
Change: 2018-10-29 08:06:15.484056316 +0530
Birth: -
```

Now we run `touch .` and then:

```
$ stat .
File: '.'
Size: 40              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 11h/17d Inode: 2338759     Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/ chronos)   Gid: ( 1000/ chronos)
Context: u:object_r:tmpfs:s0
Access: 2018-10-29 08:06:29.131056579 +0530
Modify: 2018-10-29 08:06:29.131056579 +0530
Change: 2018-10-29 08:06:29.131056579 +0530
Birth: -
```

Note how the `Access:`, `Modify:` and `Change:` fields have changed.

Comment: Thanks for listings and the stat utility, I did not know about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The short description in `man touch` says

> change file timestamps

which is what it does in this case - it updates the modified timestamp of the current directory to the current time.

Comment: Thanks. Obvious. That is a kind of information that I always miss when reading about touch (because I do not know what I would like to change the time for).

Answer (score -3):

touch [dot] create hidden file with this name (.) you can check attached image [image]

Comment: This is just not true. `.` exists in every directory, as a reference to itself.